# Can a generic approach be used to reduce average effort performed by algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have encountered (and written) code where the natural use of the standard template library in Boolean relational expressions results in (potentially) wasted effort.

For example,

```
if (std::distance(begin, end) <= 2) { ... }
```

Or:

```
if (std::count(begin,end,val) >= 3) { ... }
```

In both these cases, it is possible to write a custom algorithm to avoid unnecessary iteration/evaluation when the answer is known after a partial evaluation of the range.

Is there a generic approach that can be used to prevent wasted effort in these situations?

**EDIT:** Trying to address the "close" votes.

For example, I could implement `bool distance_at_least(begin, end, 3)` *and* `bool distance_at_most(begin, end, 2)` *and* `bool count_at_least(begin, end, val, 5)`, etc.

I am asking for a single (generic) approach that can be used for all these types of queries.

**EDIT:** Here is a mock-up of a solution for one variant, which tries to convey why I am not keen to write many variants.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

namespace DETAIL {

    template <class ITER, class CAT>
    bool distance_at_least_dispatch(ITER begin, ITER end, typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::difference_type n, CAT)
    {
        while (begin != end && n > 0) {
            ++begin;
            --n;
        }
        return n == 0;
    }

    template <class ITER>
    bool distance_at_least_dispatch(ITER begin, ITER end, typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::difference_type n, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
    {
        return std::distance(begin, end) >= n;
    }
}

template <class ITER>
bool distance_at_least(ITER begin, ITER end, typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::difference_type n)
{
    using CAT = typename std::iterator_traits<ITER>::iterator_category;
    return DETAIL::distance_at_least_dispatch(begin, end, n, CAT());
}

int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::list<int> l;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 5, std::rand);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(l), 5, std::rand);

    std::cout << distance_at_least(v.begin(), v.end(), 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << distance_at_least(v.begin(), v.end(), 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << distance_at_least(v.begin(), v.end(), 6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << distance_at_least(l.begin(), l.end(), 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << distance_at_least(l.begin(), l.end(), 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << distance_at_least(l.begin(), l.end(), 6) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In terms of algorithm complexity, both are linear (having forward iterators) and you can not do better. If you have to, profile your code.

Comment: Measure, measure correctly, measure again with different targets. No one can tell from your given _"evidence"_/missing context.

Comment: I agree the complexity is the same.  If the average value of `std::distance(begin, end)` is 100 and I only care to know >= 3, this is relevant.

Comment: You could write a generic method to handle things like this. I don't know if there's a standard implementation sitting out there already for this. Are you asking how you could do it, or whether it's already sitting there to be found and used?

Comment: Both.  If it's there, I'm happy to use it.  If it's not there, I would like to know how to build a generic approach.

Comment: There is no 'generic approach' here. Basically, what you are saying is that standard algos are not suited for you. std::distance() measures distance between two iterators, but if you only care about distance being not greater than X, you need you own distance which would stop after 5th element. On the other hand, I am hard-pressed to find real application of this. I know when you need a real distance, but when would you need to know if distance is less than 42? No idea.

Comment: Write a template function called `verify` that takes a minimum target value, two iterators/pointers/whatever of template type `T` and a function pointer/comparator class instance/whatever that implements a method that takes a value of type T and returns true if it is to be counted and false otherwise. The `verify` function will then begin iterating over the range `start` to `end` and calling the passed in method to see whether the element is counted. If it is counted, increment. Once the minimum target is reached, return. For "count": put the comparison you desire in there. For "distance":

Comment: always return true to count each element along the way.

Comment: I am upvoting because I have encountered these problems myself and wondered if there was a standard solution. Sometimes you have a huge amount of data and only care if an element occurs a small number of times.

Comment: @Patrick87: That feels like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: You can implement a `count_at_least` function by calling `std::find` and varients in a loop, passing the result to the next find call, until a certain number of iterations have been reached.

Comment: Yes.  Maybe my failure is my ability to communicate.  I can write all the variants correctly.  I am just looking for an alternative to laboriously writing all the variants.

Comment: Yes MarkB, it was meant as an answer, but the question was closed first. I put some brief notes in the comment in case they are helpful to you. Good luck.

Comment: @DieterLücking If you want to check if the distance is below a constant number of spaces, say 5, then the smart algorithm takes the same time whether the whole data structure is 50, 100, or 99999 elements. Therefore are you sure it is linear?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main question here should be whether `std::count(b,e,v) < 2` is that bad on decent compilers. It's a template function, so the full implementation is available at the point of call, and it's a fairly simple function. This makes it a prime candidate for inlining. That means that the optimizer will see that the count return value is compared against `<2`, followed by a branch. It is also visible that the count is incremented by one at a time, and that there are no side effects.

Hence, it's possible to reshuffle the code, move the branch, and eliminate the redundant part of the loop.

In pseudocode, unoptimized:

```
count = 0
:loop
if (*b==v) ++count
++b
if(b!=e) goto loop
if(count >=2) goto past_if
// Then-block
:past_if
```

And now optimized

```
count = 0
:loop
if (*b==v) ++count
if(count>=2) goto past_if
++b
if(b!=e) goto loop
// Then-block
:past_if
```

As you can see, this is a simple reordering. Only one line moves. This isn't rocket science, a decent optimizer should be able to figure this out.

Comment: I agree that it's possible.  Neither gcc nor MSVC++ got it right.  Another interesting experiment:  Fill a vector with 10000 ints, `return std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), val) >= 10042`.  A human obviously knows its false.  The compiler diligently walks through the values...